# React Flow Chart: Connect link when drop anywhere on node

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-chartjs

I have been using npm package react-flow-chart,
I can now create links between nodes using drag and drop.

The issue is:
I have to drop the link exactly on the port
In my case, I will always have a single input port on every node,
Is it possible to connect the link, even if I drop link anywhere on the target node,
(not exactly on the port)

[image]

Look at the image,
Is it possible if I drop the link from source node anywhere on the target node and still I can connect the link.
Let's say the input portId will be static, For Instance take portId = "in"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution myself,

onLinkCancel event, I get the drop location of link
I can check whether this position falls inside any node,
using node positions, their height and width !!

```
onLinkCancel: ({linkId, toPosition, fromNodeId, fromPortId}) => chartObj => { 
    for (let node of <nodes array>) {
        if (toPosition.x >= node.position.x && node.size && toPosition.x <= (node.position.x + node.size.width) && toPosition.y >= node.position.y && toPosition.y <= (node.position.y + node.size.height) ) { 
targetNodeId = node.id; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: sure @7ball

onLinkCancel: ({linkId, toPosition, fromNodeId, fromPortId}) => chartObj => {
         for (let node of <nodes' array>) {
                    if (toPosition.x >= node.position.x && node.size && toPosition.x <= (node.position.x + node.size.width)
                        && toPosition.y >= node.position.y && toPosition.y <= (node.position.y + node.size.height)
                    ) {
                        targetNodeId = node.id;
                    }
                }
}